# Get list of data-* attributes using javascript / jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, attributes, custom-data-attribute

Given an arbitrary HTML element with zero or more `data-*` attributes, how can one retrieve a list of key-value pairs for the data.

E.g. given this:

```
<div id='prod' data-id='10' data-cat='toy' data-cid='42'>blah</div>
```

I would like to be able to programmatically retrieve this:

```
{ "id":10, "cat":"toy", "cid":42 }
```

Using jQuery (v1.4.3), accessing the individual bits of data using `$.data()` is simple if the keys are known in advance, but it is not obvious how one can do so with arbitrary sets of data.

I'm looking for a 'simple' jQuery solution if one exists, but would not mind a lower level approach otherwise. I had a go at trying to to parse `$('#prod').attributes` but my lack of javascript-fu is letting me down.

### update

[customdata](https://github.com/ubilabs/jquery-customdata) does what I need. However, including a jQuery plugin just for a fraction of its functionality seemed like an overkill.

Eyeballing the source helped me fix my own code (and improved my javascript-fu).

Here's the solution I came up with:

```
function getDataAttributes(node) {
    var d = {}, 
        re_dataAttr = /^data\-(.+)$/;

    $.each(node.get(0).attributes, function(index, attr) {
        if (re_dataAttr.test(attr.nodeName)) {
            var key = attr.nodeName.match(re_dataAttr)[1];
            d[key] = attr.nodeValue;
        }
    });

    return d;
}
```

### update 2

As demonstrated in the accepted answer, the solution is trivial with jQuery (>=1.4.4). `$('#prod').data()` would return the required data dict.

Comment: Addresing "update 2" be aware of jquery data() use some internal cache and data(key, value) does not propagate to DOM, which can cause lot of headaches.

Also since jquery 3 data() convert attribute data-some-thing="test" into {someThing: "test"}

Comment: Note that even at the time of this question, the plain JS solution was to just use the built-in [element.dataset](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset) property, although the "as plain object, not DOMStringMap" solution would take another two years, when `Object.assign({}, element.dataset)` became a built-in solution (although technically, `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(element.dataset))` _was_ an option, although was just as questionable then as it is today =).

Answer (score 105, accepted):

Actually, if you're working with jQuery, as of version <del>1.4.3</del> 1.4.4 (because of the bug as mentioned in the comments below), `data-*` attributes are supported through [`.data()`](http://api.jquery.com/data/):

> As of jQuery 1.4.3 HTML 5 `data-`
>   attributes will be automatically
>   pulled in to jQuery's data object.
>
> Note that strings are left intact
>   while JavaScript values are converted
>   to their associated value (this
>   includes booleans, numbers, objects,
>   arrays, and null). The `data-`
>   attributes are pulled in the first
>   time the data property is accessed and
>   then are no longer accessed or mutated
>   (all data values are then stored
>   internally in jQuery).

The `jQuery.fn.data` function will return all of the `data-` attribute inside an object as key-value pairs, with the key being the part of the attribute name after `data-` and the value being the value of that attribute after being converted following the rules stated above.

I've also created a simple demo if that doesn't convince you: http://jsfiddle.net/yijiang/WVfSg/

Comment: No, this is [broken in 1.4.3](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/7222). A minimum of 1.4.4 is explicitly required.

Comment: Thanks. That's exactly what I was looking for. I previously tried that with 1.4.3 and didn't go very far. jsfiddle demo helped too.

Comment: @Isc: one thing that is very annoying is jQuery's attempt at "deserializing" the value found in the attribute (i.e. [from master](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/commit/8a5df39045292397a06d08b4fab2ad29819b5d44/): `!jQuery.isNaN( data ) ? parseFloat( data ) : ...`). I had product serial numbers in my attribute such as `data-serial="00071134"` which jQuery munged into a number `71134`, forcing me to revert to the less elegant `.attr('data-serial')` (not an option in your case). I've seen questions on SO that have voiced similar frustrations wrt `.data()`, will try to dig one out...

Comment: @CrescentFresh: Good point. Definitely something I should watch out for. In my solution (https://gist.github.com/701652) I fall back to parsing node.attributes when jQuery<1.4.3 ; with this issue in mind, perhaps I should simply stick with manually parsing the attributes.

Comment: @Lsc: yes your <= 1.4.3 implementation does not match jQuery's as far as the "smart" parsing jQuery tries to do. I would have actually preferred if jQuery's implementation matched the simplicity of yours :)

Comment: Keep in mind that `$.data()` also returns anything you've stored using `$.data(key, value)`. If you truly want to check if something is actually stored in the markup as a data-* attribute, this method might not be the best choice.

Comment: I was also burned by `$.data()`'s [camel-casing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22753629/jquery-get-html-5-data-attributes-with-hyphens-and-case-sensitivity) behavior.

Comment: how can i add these attributes to a variable to be used on another element?

Answer (score 91):

A pure JavaScript solution ought to be offered as well, as the solution is not difficult:

```
var a = [].filter.call(el.attributes, function(at) { return /^data-/.test(at.name); });
```

This gives an array of attribute objects, which have `name` and `value` properties:

```
if (a.length) {
    var firstAttributeName = a[0].name;
    var firstAttributeValue = a[0].value;
}
```

**Edit:** To take it a step further, you can get a dictionary by iterating the attributes and populating a data object:

```
var data = {};
[].forEach.call(el.attributes, function(attr) {
    if (/^data-/.test(attr.name)) {
        var camelCaseName = attr.name.substr(5).replace(/-(.)/g, function ($0, $1) {
            return $1.toUpperCase();
        });
        data[camelCaseName] = attr.value;
    }
});
```

You could then access the value of, for example, `data-my-value="2"` as `data.myValue`;

[jsfiddle.net/3KFYf/33](http://jsfiddle.net/3KFYf/33/)

**Edit:** If you wanted to set data attributes on your element programmatically from an object, you could:

```
Object.keys(data).forEach(function(key) {
    var attrName = "data-" + key.replace(/[A-Z]/g, function($0) {
        return "-" + $0.toLowerCase();
    });
    el.setAttribute(attrName, data[key]);
});
```

[jsfiddle.net/3KFYf/34](http://jsfiddle.net/3KFYf/34/)

**EDIT:** If you are using babel or TypeScript, or coding only for es6 browsers, this is a nice place to use es6 arrow functions, and shorten the code a bit:

```
var a = [].filter.call(el.attributes, at => /^data-/.test(at.name));
```

Comment: Good answer! The first line does not replace the `-` character like jQuery does but the edited answer does.

Comment: @gilly3 Your jsfiddle doesn't seem to work. Can you have a look?

Comment: @Ethan - Fixed.  Thanks for letting me know.  I had been using beautify.js from [jsbeautifier.org](http://jsbeautifier.org) to pretty print the JSON.  Apparently that link is broken now.  But, that was overkill since `JSON.stringify()` has JSON formatting built in.

Comment: @gilly3 Fantastic, your routine is great to fetch all. Would it be easy to add fetch data for a given key as well as to update modified data for key(s)? If you can share, that would be great.

Comment: @Ethan - For getting a single value, don't overthink it:  `el.getAttribute("data-foo")`.  I've updated my answer to show how you could set data attributes based on an object.

Comment: @gilly3 Thanks for the code. Yes, I shouldn't overthink to get that done, but however, having similar data within the code makes it more readable. However, I should be able to write it up quickly.

Comment: Contains all the questions / answers i was looking for!

Answer (score 27):

[Have a look here](http://html5doctor.com/html5-custom-data-attributes/):

If the browser also supports the HTML5 JavaScript API, you should be able to get the data with:

```
var attributes = element.dataset
```

or

```
var cat = element.dataset.cat
```

Oh, but I also read:

> Unfortunately, the new dataset property has not yet been implemented in any browser, so in the meantime it’s best to use `getAttribute` and `setAttribute` as demonstrated earlier.

It is from May 2010.

---

If you use jQuery anyway, you might want to have a look at the [**customdata**](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/customdata) plugin. I have no experience with it though.

Comment: Also of interest, from ppk: http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_core.html#attributes

Comment: Thanks Felix. I had come across customdata. Unfortunately, it does not do what I need -- i.e. get all data given that keys are not known in advance.

Comment: @lsc: The documentation says that `$("#my").customdata()` should give you `{method: "delete", remote: "true"}`... so it should work.

Comment: Using a separate jQuery plugin seems like an overkill, but looking at the source for customdata helped my fix my own solutions! Will accept your answer and update Q with working function.

Comment: @Felix: Appreciate your answer, but Yi Jiang's a closer match to what I was looking for, hence moved "accepted" to his. Many thanks.

Comment: @lsc: Totally fine, build in solutions should always be preferred imo. Unfortunately I'm not up-to-date with the latest jQuery development ;) Just wondering why someone voted me down...

Answer (score 12):

As mentioned above [modern browsers](http://caniuse.com/#feat=dataset) have the [*The HTMLElement.dataset*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset) API.
That API gives you a [DOMStringMap](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMStringMap), and you can retrieve the list of `data-*` attributes simply doing:

```
var dataset = el.dataset; // as you asked in the question
```

you can also retrieve a array with the `data-` property's key names like

```
var data = Object.keys(el.dataset);
```

or map its values by

```
Object.keys(el.dataset).map(function(key){ return el.dataset[key];});
// or the ES6 way: Object.keys(el.dataset).map(key=>{ return el.dataset[key];});
```

and like this you can iterate those and use them without the need of filtering between all attributes of the element [like we needed to do before](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5915585/2256325).

Answer (score 3):

You should be get the data through the dataset attributes

```
var data = element.dataset;
```

[dataset](https://github.com/mui-lychi/dataset) is useful tool for get data-attribute

Comment: IIRC, `this.dataset` does not work on all browsers yet. There is however a [jquery plugin](http://www.orangesoda.net/jquery.dataset.html) which provides this feature.

Answer (score 3):

or convert `gilly3`'s excellent answer to a jQuery method:

```
$.fn.info = function () {
    var data = {};
    [].forEach.call(this.get(0).attributes, function (attr) {
        if (/^data-/.test(attr.name)) {
            var camelCaseName = attr.name.substr(5).replace(/-(.)/g, function ($0, $1) {
                return $1.toUpperCase();
            });
            data[camelCaseName] = attr.value;
        }
    });
    return data;
}
```

Using: `$('.foo').info()`;

Answer (score 2):

You can just iterate over the data attributes like any other object to get keys and values, here's how to do it with `$.each`:

```
    $.each($('#myEl').data(), function(key, value) {
        console.log(key);
        console.log(value);
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

I use nested [each](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/) - for me this is the easiest solution (Easy to control/change "what you do with the values - in my example output data-attributes as `ul-list`) (Jquery Code)

```js
var model = $(".model");

var ul = $("<ul>").appendTo("body");

$(model).each(function(index, item) {
  ul.append($(document.createElement("li")).text($(this).text()));
  $.each($(this).data(), function(key, value) {
    ul.append($(document.createElement("strong")).text(key + ": " + value));
    ul.append($(document.createElement("br")));
  }); //inner each
  ul.append($(document.createElement("hr")));
}); // outer each

/*print html*/
var htmlString = $("ul").html();
$("code").text(htmlString);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prism/1.17.1/prism.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prism/1.17.1/themes/prism-okaidia.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1 id="demo"></h1>

<ul>
  <li class="model" data-price="45$" data-location="Italy" data-id="1234">Model 1</li>
  <li class="model" data-price="75$" data-location="Israel" data-id="4321">Model 2</li> 
  <li class="model" data-price="99$" data-location="France" data-id="1212">Model 3</li> 
</ul>

<pre>
<code class="language-html">
  
</code>
</pre>

<h2>Generate list by code</h2>
<br>
```

Codepen: https://codepen.io/ezra_siton/pen/GRgRwNw?editors=1111

Answer (score 1):

100% Javascript no jQuery ;)

DOMStringMap :

```
  console.log(document.getElementById('target-element-id').dataset);
```

or custom variable :

```
  var data = {};

  Object.entries(document.getElementById('target-element-id').dataset).forEach(([key, val]) => {
    data[key] = val;
  });

  console.log(data);
```

Answer (score 0):

One way of finding all data attributes is using [`element.attributes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/attributes). Using `.attributes`, you can loop through all of the element attributes, filtering out the items which include the string "data-".

```
let element = document.getElementById("element");

function getDataAttributes(element){
    let elementAttributes = {},
        i = 0;

    while(i < element.attributes.length){
        if(element.attributes[i].name.includes("data-")){
            elementAttributes[element.attributes[i].name] = element.attributes[i].value
        }
        i++;
    }

    return elementAttributes;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know the name of keys you can also use object destructuring to get values like this

```
const {id, cat, cid } = document.getElementById('prod').dataset;
```

You can also skip keys you don't need and get the ones you need like this

```
const { cid, id } = document.getElementById('prod').dataset;
```