# Retrieve all data-* attributes from an element

Tags: javascript, html, custom-data-attribute

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Get list of data-* attributes using javascript / jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4187032/get-list-of-data-attributes-using-javascript-jquery)

How would you go about retrieving all the data attributes from an element, and throw them into an array?

For example, if I have a list element:

```
<li id="the_example" class="haz_data" data-foo="omega" data-bar="zeta" data-derp="psi">Hello, world!</li>
```

I'd love to be able to grab all those data attributes and end up with an array or object like this (or something similar):

```
[{foo:omega},{bar:zeta},{derp:psi}]
```

A solution where you don't know the data attribute names would be preferred.

Comment: Are you using jQuery? the .data() method will yield an object of all data attributes or a single one by key.

Comment: Ya, jQuery, but I only want the data-s

Comment: @Ian and I thought my searching was good. Dammit, good find.

Comment: As pointed by @Ian Pugsley, your solution can be found [here](http://jsfiddle.net/yijiang/WVfSg/), on the thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4187032/get-list-of-data-attributes-using-javascript-jquery.

Answer (score 0):

Make a nice Javascript attay and then use jquery to convert the array

http://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/

or

http://www.google.co.uk/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=asp+json+dday#hl=en&pq=asp%20json&xhr=t&q=jquery+array+to+json&cp=15&pf=p&sclient=psy&source=hp&aq=0&aqi=&aql=&oq=jquery+array+to&pbx=1&fp=a19d57c9b1bb4a83