# how to create custom attribute for html tag.ex:<div class="header" cust-data="hide"></div>

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

**how to create custom attribute for html tag.**

Sample HTML Code:

```
<div class="header" custom-data-attribute="hide"> sample text </div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `data-*` HTML5 attribute:

```
<div class="header" data-custom-attribute="hide"> sample text </div>
```

then apply **[.data()](http://api.jquery.com/data/)** to set the value:

```
$('div.header').data("custom-attribute","value here");
```

and retrieve the value using:

```
var customAttr = $('div.header').data("custom-attribute");
```

Comment: This is the only answer from the view of OP. +1

Comment: +1 for quick and better solution. But we need to be careful while using data-attributes. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22753629/jquery-get-html-5-data-attributes-with-hyphens-and-case-sensitivity

Answer (score 1):

Try using [`.attr()`](https://api.jquery.com/attr/) function,

```
$('div.header').attr('custom-data-attribute','hide');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.attr()` or `.prop()`. Try this:

```
 $('div.header').attr("custom-data-attribute","hide");
```

or

```
 $('div.header').prop("custom-data-attribute","hide");
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/HLVnY/)**