# Can't seem to update data attribute using .data()

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to update my data attribute, but my code doesn't work. Don't see what i'm missing

```
<tr class="sell-figures" rel="sell-id">
      <th></th>
      <td class="" data-sell-id="1"></td>
      <td class="" data-sell-id="12"></td>
      <td class="" data-sell-id="123"></td>
      <td class="" data-sell-id="1234"></td>
</tr>
```

and here is my jquery

```
$(".sell-figures tr[rel=sell-id] td:nth(3)").data("sell-id", '999');
```

I'm trying to change 1234 to 999. what am i doing wrong here? Thanks

Comment: Are you trying to update the value of the data-sell-id attribute? jquery .data associates information with the element, but doesn't update the attribute value.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22753629/jquery-get-html-5-data-attributes-with-hyphens-and-case-sensitivity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do it. It will select item with class `sell-figures` and then on the 4th child will set attribute to `data-sell-id` to `999`

```
$(".sell-figures>td:nth(3)").attr("data-sell-id", '999');
```

Comment: That won't work, it will look for an attribute named `data-data-sell-id`.

Comment: Really? Is that a new CSS or jQuery selector? I'm not familiar with it.

Comment: @user2636556 You can use `.data()` to read the attribute, but then jQuery caches it internally and doesn't update it in the DOM.

Answer (score 0):

Your selector is incorrect. Use:

```
$("tr[rel=sell-id].sell-figures td:nth-child(3)").data("sell-id", '999');
```

Comment: @user2636556 you know that using `.data()` will not change the attribute itself, right?

Comment: @user2636556 - Can you elaborate on your "don't work" comment? What exactly "don't work"?