# what are data-* HTML attributes?

Tags: javascript, html

I've recently found on one of the sites opening  tag like this:

`<script data-ip="93.1xx.3.2x" data-backuri="something.com">`

And I couldn't find any information about it. What are those tags used for?

Comment: Those are data attributes https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes and are custom attributes used by the developer to store some data in the view. The developer probably gets the values and does something with them in his scripts

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`data-*` attributes are custom HTML attributes.

Basically, there are standard HTML attributes like `style`, `src`, `width`, `height`, `class`... and these have a special meaning to browsers and are 'reserved'.

However, custom attributes have no special meaning generally and are only special to the owner's application. They can be used to simplify an application's logic.

Using `data-` before your attribute name ensures that future standard attributes will not use your current attribute. For example, imagine today you are using a `sound` attribute but then the HTML standard adds a `sound` attribute meaning something other than what you meant. Had you used `data-sound`, you would have been fine because there would be no conflict. The specification says no future standard browser attributes will start with `data-`.

See [jquery get HTML 5 Data Attributes with hyphens and Case Sensitivity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22753629/jquery-get-html-5-data-attributes-with-hyphens-and-case-sensitivity) for some useful info on why we use `data-*` attributes.

Also, see [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes) for some useful information.