# what "<div data-async-context="query:"></div>" means in html and what i can do with "query:"?

Tags: javascript, html, xss

I know simple stuff like `onload` `onerror` but I can't find what `data-async-context` use for

also I know what `javascript:alert()` doe's but I don't understand how I can use `query:` and if `query` is like `Element.querySelector()` in javascript

can you please help me understand how to use it?

i tried to look at https://metacpan.org/pod/HTML::Query

Comment: [Duplicate](https://google.com/search?q=site%3Astackoverflow.com+html+what+are+data+attributes) of [what are data-\* HTML attributes?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30417852/4642212). What `async-context` and `query:` mean, specifically, depends on the application, framework, or library. This doesn’t have any specific meaning in HTML or JavaScript itself.

Comment: can you show me an example how to use `query:`

Comment: No, I can’t. As I said, the meaning of `query:` depends on whatever application uses it. I don’t know which technology stack you’re using, since you’ve never mentioned it. It has nothing to do with `querySelector`. [Googling `"data-async-context"`](https://google.com/search?q="data-async-context") shows a few results. Maybe one of them explains what it means.

Comment: ok ty i understand