# what is data-email,which is used as an attribute in a tag?

Tags: html, attributes, tags

**Why is data-email used as an attribute here ? What is the use of it?**

```html
 <div id="sidebar">
      <h3>Contact our team :</h3>
      <ul id="nav">
         <li><a data-email="rohansharma@gmail.com" href="mailto:rohansharma@gmail.com">Rohan Sharma</a></li>
         <li><a data-email="rahulneha@gmail.com" href="mailto:rahulneha@gmail.com">Rahul Kumar</a></li>
         <li><a data-email="neharahul@me.com" href="mailto:neharahul@me.com">Neha Sharma</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
```

Comment: You can learn data attributes [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [what are data-\* HTML attributes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30417852/what-are-data-html-attributes)