# values remain empty when passing trough data-id

Tags: php, jquery, html

I ran google multiple times but the answer remains unclear.

i pass data trough data-id in html. this contains a timestamp like this one "2015-11-01"  when i console.log this in jquery the value is empty.

Help much appreciated

Code:

```
data-timeIndacation="<?php echo $time1; ?>" in html / php
```

Code:

`var timeIndacation   = $("#CanavaslineChartData").data("timeIndacation");
console.log(timeIndacation);`

Output:

> undefined

Comment: The value $time1 is a valid variable. when running var_dump(); it returns the obvious.

Comment: data attributes have to be lowercase see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22753629/jquery-get-html-5-data-attributes-with-hyphens-and-case-sensitivity

Comment: Thanks @AlexAndrei this resolved the isssue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`data` attribute must be in lowercase. Try with -

```
data-timeindacation
```