# Populate data from groovy controller in pop up

Tags: javascript, grails, groovy

I have a gsp page with a delete button for each row of a table. On the button click I want a pop up which tells the consequences of the delete. These consequences depends on the data present in the row and a few other constraints known to the grails service which is called from the grails controller associated to the gsp page. If the user confirms these consequences the row should be deleted from the table, else the table remains unchanged.

How should i go about to achieve this behavior?

Currently, I have in my gsp

```
<tr>
    <td>name</td>
    <td>parentName</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>
        <g:link action="deleteRow" params="${[name: row.name, parentName: row.parentName]}">
            <button class="deleteSnapshot">Delete</button>
        </g:link>
    </td>
</tr>
```

and in my .js file

```
$(document).on('click', ':button', function (e) {
        var btn = $(e.target);
        btn.attr("disabled", "disabled"); // disable button
        alert('getting deletion details');
        //var deletionDetails -->not sure how to get these
        //var deletionDetails will get data from controller action:"getDetails"
        if (confirm('/*print deletion details and ask*/ Do you want to proceed?')) {
            alert('will delete')
            return true
        }
        else {
            btn.removeAttr("disabled"); // enable button
            return false
        }
    });
```

and in my controller

```
class DeleteController{
    DeleteService deleteService
    def index() {
        [list:deleteService.getTableList()]
    }
    def getDeletionDetails(string name, String parentName){
        return deleteService.getDetails(name,parentName)
    }
    def deleteRow(String name, String parentName){
        service.deleteRow(name, parentName)
        redirect controller:"DeleteController", action:"index"
    }
}
```

I know the deletion works fine, because it works even with in the current state. Just that the confirmation box asks Do you want to proceed, without displaying the details.

Any help on how i could achieve what I am looking for will be appreciated.

P.S. I am new to stackoverflow, so if i missed out on certain convention do let me know.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can think of two ways of doing it:

#### The first one is using *ajax* to both get deletion details and delete the row

Assuming that *deleteService.getDetails(name, parentName)* returns a String,
first you need to change an *getDeletionDetails* action so it renders the response:

```
def getDeletionDetails(String name, String parentName){
    render deleteService.getDetails(name, parentName)
}
```

and change *g:link*-s to buttons in *gsp*:

```
<button data-name="${row.name}" data-parent-name="${row.parentName}">
     Delete
</button>
```

In your .js then put:

```
$(document).on('click', ':button', function (e) {
    var btn = $(e.target);

    btn.attr("disabled", "disabled"); // disable button

    var name = btn.data('name');
    var parentName = btn.data('parentName');

    $.ajax({
        url: "/delete/getDeletionDetails",
        data: {
            name: name,
            parentName: parentName
        },
        success: function (data) {
            if (confirm(data + '\nDo you want to proceed?')) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: '/delete/deleteRow',
                    data: {
                        name: name,
                        parentName: parentName
                    },
                    success: function (d) {
                        console.log("Success: " + d);
                    }
                });
            } else {
                btn.removeAttr("disabled"); // enable button
            }
        }
    });
});
```

What this code does is it sends an ajax call to */delete/getDeletionDetails*, then uses its response (rendered by *getDeletionDetails* action in *DeleteController*) to show a confirmation alert. If user confirms the question, another ajax call is sent - now to *deleteRow* action of *DeleteController* - with parameters taken from data attributes of clicked button. If user cancels - nothing happens, except for reenabling a button.

Your *deleteRow* should only change the return statement - it also must render the response:

```
def deleteRow(String name, String parentName){
    service.deleteRow(name, parentName)
    render "You deleted an item $name - $parentName."
}
```

You don't need *redirect* here, because - thanks to using ajax - user will never leave *delete/index*. You can just display some kind of confirmation on page after successful ajax call.

#### The second option is to put deletion details in hidden fields or *data-* attributes in each row and then just retrieve them in *js*:

You can create a method *getDeletionDetails()* in *row*'s domain class (presumably *Row*) that returns the details (using services in domain classes is not perfect, but is should work ok if the service is not very complex). Then, in your *.gsp* place:

```
<td>
    <g:link action="deleteRow" params="${[name: row.name, parentName: row.parentName]}">
        <button class="deleteSnapshot" data-details="${row.deletionDetails}">Delete</button>
    </g:link>
</td>
```

You should then be able to get details in *.js* like this:

```
var deletionDetails = btn.data('details');
```

Comment: Thanks @suricatta. This is amazing. It worked exactly the way i needed it to. I just had a doubt and a question.
1. Why does "data-parent-name="${row.parentName}" work and "data-parentName="${row.parentName}" not work in my gsp page?

2. After the delete, the row is deleted from the database but not from the page. I need to refresh the page for the like to disappear. Is this because we removed the redirect?

Once again, thanks a lot, not only for the solution but actually typing the whole code down here with detailed explanation. 
It is very helpful for a noob like me. :-)

Comment: Also, I used solution 1, even though I tried both the solutions and they worked just fine.

Comment: @VaibhavKarani Ad. 1. I'm afraid I don't have enough information to answer this question. What do you mean by "not work in my gsp page"? Ad. 2. Yes - the view doesn't change because everything is done by ajax - you can remove the row manually in the _success_ callback of the ajax call using jQuery (find the _tr_ and _.remove()_ it, it shouldn't be difficult).

Comment: What i meant was that when i use the solution mentioned by you, it works fine and the name and the parentName are received correctly.

However, when i use data-parentName="${row.parentName}" instead of data-parent-name="${row.parentName} in my gsp page, the value captured by the .js is null.

Why is the working so?

Comment: @VaibhavKarani I think now data attributes should be lowercase: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22753630/2224598, so maybe using `.data('parentname')` will work. Also, if the solution worked, would you mind  accepting the answer?

Comment: Thanks @suricatta for the help. I have accepted the solution. Could you too please upvote the question. :-)

Comment: Sure, @VaibhavKarani, it was well written question.