# Converting data-* attributes to an object

Tags: javascript, html, data-binding

I'm playing around with the [attr-data-*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes#attr-data-*) attributes of HTML5 and the corresponding javascript [dataset](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement.dataset)

I'm doing alot of dynamic form processing, so I end up getting stuff like this:

```
<input data-feaux="bar" data-fizz="buzz"/>
```

Since `HTMLElement.dataset` returns a `DOM string map`, the only way I can figure out how to convert it into an native object is:

```
var obj = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(input_el.dataset))
```

Is there a better way to do this?

**Edit:**

Why would I want to do this? Let's say I have many, many of these elements. I want to loop through them all and push them into an array for processing later, i.e.

```
elements = document.querySelectorAll("input")
my_data_array = []
for(var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    my_data_array.push(elements[i].dataset)
}
```

Now I have an array of objects, i.e. `[{feaux: "bar", fizz:"buzz"}....]` that I can work with.

However, when I don't convert the `DOM string map` into an object, the array doesn't get populated (i.e. the code above doesn't work)

**Edit 2**

Looking closer, it is actually a `DOM string map`, not an `object`. Correcting typos in the original question to reflect this.

Comment: It already is an object. Why do you want it to be native?

Comment: @cookiemonster because `DOM string object` doesn't like being pushed into an array and I loose the keys; I've edited my question to give an example

Comment: In what browser does that not work? Works fine for me in Firefox. ...works in Chrome too.

Comment: ...anyway, if you wanted to store the `dataset` objects, you might as well store the elements themselves since storing the `dataset` is going to retain a reference to the element since the `dataset` relies on the element to work.

Comment: @cookiemonster yeah, I can get this to work in the console of Chrome, but some reason loading it from a script file or running it with a headless web browser, the `DOM string maps` don't go into the array correctly. I'm going to be doing more testing; this could be a bug higher up in the line :P

Answer (score 48, accepted):

You can use [Object.assign](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign)

```
Object.assign({}, element.dataset)
```

For browsers that doesn't support Object.assign you can use [polyfill](https://github.com/zloirock/core-js#ecmascript-6-object)

Comment: On latest Safari this doesn't works. Returns always empty {} So you need to transform dataset to a normal object first.

Comment: was just bitten by this one. Safari 9.x fails. Safari 10.x + works.

Answer (score 12):

in es6 you can use the object spread.
`{ ...element.dataset }`

Answer (score 9):

Don't forget about JSON.stringify and JSON.parse.

```
var data = document.getElementById('someElement').dataset;
data = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data));
```

According to [Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) this should work all the way back to IE 8 without a polyfill.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a little function to retrieve the element dataset as a normal object:

```
function datasetToObject(elem){
    var data = {};
    [].forEach.call(elem.attributes, function(attr) {
        if (/^data-/.test(attr.name)) {
            var camelCaseName = attr.name.substr(5).replace(/-(.)/g, function ($0, $1) {
                return $1.toUpperCase();
            });
            data[camelCaseName] = attr.value;
        }
    });
    return data;
}
```

Scooped up from:
[Get list of data-* attributes using javascript / jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4187032/get-list-of-data-attributes-using-javascript-jquery)