# I need to get all data attributes & value like key:value pair of a ul li

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a `ul` tag with few `li` elements. Each `li` have some data attributes.

```
<ul id="elements">
<li id="mtq" data-id="1" data-name="abc">test 1</li>
<li data-id="2">test 2</li>
<li data-id="3" data-name="xyz">test 3</li>
<li data-id="4" data-name="pqr">test 4</li>
<li data-id="5" data-type="text">test 5</li>
<li data-id="7">test 6</li>
</ul>
```

I need to get all data attributes (without `date-` string) & value of each `li` like key:value like below one.

`{"id":1,"name":"abc"}`

I tried the below javascript code, but I got an error that says `Array.prototype.forEach called on null or undefined`.

```
function getDataAttributes(el) {
    var data = {};
    [].forEach.call(el.attributes, function(attr) {
        if (/^data-/.test(attr.name)) {
            var camelCaseName = attr.name.substr(5).replace(/-(.)/g, function ($0, $1) {
                return $1.toUpperCase();
            });
            data[camelCaseName] = attr.value;
        }
    });
    return data;
}

$("#hello").click( function (e) {

    $("ul#elements li").each(function() {
    var data = getDataAttributes($(this));
    console.log(data);
    //var json = JSON.stringify(data, null, 2);
    //el.appendChild(document.createTextNode(json));
    });

});
```

Here is my jsfiddle. https://jsfiddle.net/a4vya9m4/26/

When I select one `li` by ID, it give answer. What is wrong in my script?

Comment: `el.attributes` - you are trying to access a DOM element property here, but `el` is a jQuery object. Just pass the DOM element into the function to begin with, `getDataAttributes(this)`

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23703044/converting-data-attributes-to-an-object

Comment: @CBroe , Seriously I don't know the difference between `$(this)` & `this`. But after reading your comment, I have searched & just updated my code.
`var data = getDataAttributes(this);` & got the result. Now I understood what you are saying.

Comment: Check out [Difference between $(this) and this in jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3633270/difference-between-this-and-this-in-jquery)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use `dataset`

> The HTMLElement.dataset property allows access, both in reading and
>   writing mode, to all the custom data attributes (data-*) set on the
>   element, either in HTML or in the DOM.

Check snippet:

```js
$(function() {

  let result = $("#elements>li").map(function() {
    let o = this;
    return Object.keys(o.dataset).reduce(function(c, v) { c[v] = o.dataset[v]; return c;}, {})
  }).get();

  console.log(result);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="elements">
  <li id="mtq" data-id="1" data-name="abc">test 1</li>
  <li data-id="2">test 2</li>
  <li data-id="3" data-name="xyz">test 3</li>
  <li data-id="4" data-name="pqr">test 4</li>
  <li data-id="5" data-type="text">test 5</li>
  <li data-id="7">test 6</li>
</ul>
```

For more info: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset

Answer (score 3):

You're overthinking the `getDataAttributes`, you can take the dataset in your `el`, that already have what you need.

```
function getDataAttributes(el) {
    if(el[0] && el[0].dataset) {
        return Object.assign({}, el[0].dataset);
    }
    return {};
}
```

the `el[0].dataset`will return you a `DOMStringMap`, that's why I use the `Object.assing` to convert it into a normal Object.

Hope this help you.

Answer (score 2):

Use the below code

```
$("#hello").click( function (e) {

    $("ul#elements li").each(function() {
        var data = $(this).data()
        console.log(data);
    }); 
});
```

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

you can use `$(elem).data()` to get all data attribute and key

```js
$(function(){
  var result = [];
  $('#elements li').each(function(i,e){
   var data = $(this).data();
   if(Object.keys(data).length){//is obj (data) empty or not
    var temp = {};
    for (var key in data) {
     temp[key] = data[key];
    }
    result.push(temp);
   }
  });
  console.log(result);
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="elements">
<li id="mtq" data-id="1" data-name="abc">test 1</li>
<li data-id="2">test 2</li>
<li data-id="3" data-name="xyz">test 3</li>
<li data-id="4" data-name="pqr">test 4</li>
<li data-id="5" data-type="text">test 5</li>
<li data-id="7">test 6</li>
<li>no data example</li>
</ul>
```