# Converting element.dataset (a DOMStringMap object) into a "real" JSON object in vanilla JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ecmascript-6

Like explained in a [similar Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23703044/converting-data-attributes-to-an-object), in vanilla JavaScript, I can do the following:

```
var data = Object.assign({}, element.dataset);
```

... in order to get all `data-*` attributes as an object.

However, the resulting object is not a "real" JSON object, booleans and numbers are surrounded by quotes.

```
<div id="my-element"
    data-string="It's OK."
    data-bool="true"
    data-number="10">
</div>
```

Here is the comparison between vanilla JavaScript and jQuery:

[image: vanilla]

[image: jquery]

I supposed that in jQuery, `jQuery('#my-element').data()` is doing the heavy job of "lifting" the data before returning the actual JSON.

Since I'd like to use ES6 and not jQuery, and I don't want to reinvent the wheel (parsing that values using regex/conditions), **I'm asking if there is a quick way to do this job**.

Comment: So, small point, but an important point that you seem to be confused on.  There is no such thing as a JSON Object.  JSON is a string.  The JSON value may contain the syntax for an object, but it is not an object.  It is a string.  And the things you are console logging are not JSON.  They are just Objects.

Comment: Sorry for being so inaccurate, yep I'm still learning JavaScript. Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 1):

The data processing in jquery is done in `getData()` function in [data.js](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/data.js)

*here is the code from JQuery library:*

```
function getData( data ) {
    if ( data === "true" ) {
        return true;
    }

    if ( data === "false" ) {
        return false;
    }

    if ( data === "null" ) {
        return null;
    }

    // Only convert to a number if it doesn't change the string
    if ( data === +data + "" ) {
        return +data;
    }
    //Replaced rbrace with regex value.
    if ( /^(?:\{[\w\W]*\}|\[[\w\W]*\])$/.test( data ) ) {
        return JSON.parse( data );
    }

    return data;
}
```

you can use this function and update your data.

Comment: How this is supposed to be called? Loop or recusive call or JSON reviver?

Comment: You loop into your object values and feed values to this function and replace with returned value.