# Extract key-value pairs from html tag formatted String

Tags: javascript

I have this string:

**edit - and I do not have access to it as html/dom/jquery**

`<meta charset="UTF-8" data-slide-length="5" data-prio="HIGH" data-freq="2">`
and I would like to extract the key-value pairs of the custom attributes (`data-`).

I have no idea where to start with the regexps and I can't seem to find a close enough example for me to understand.

desired output: {slide-length: 5, prio:"HIGH", freq:2}

Thank you

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get list of data-\* attributes using javascript / jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4187032/get-list-of-data-attributes-using-javascript-jquery)

Comment: Where do you get the string? If you are getting that string from the DOM then please mention it in the question, it would be easier to just use the element object itself to extract the data attributes.

Comment: Also will you be only using "slide-length"/"prio"/"freq" as data attribute names or they can be named anything?

Comment: This is a pure Javascript problem, I don't have access to jQuery or dom/html since I am reading it as strings from file using `'fs'` in Node.
It looks identical the [suggested link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4187032/get-list-of-data-attributes-using-javascript-jquery) but I can't seem to get it to work still.

Comment: After looking more closely, this is NOT AT ALL a duplicate from [Get list of data-* attributes using javascript / jQuery ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4187032/get-list-of-data-attributes-using-javascript-jquery). In that question it handles the html-tag as an element and can fetch attributes etc. from the `dom`.

In my question, just as the header states, I am dealing with simply a string.

Comment: Buf if you have the string, you can parse as DOM – even in memory – and then access to the attributes. What's your context exactly? Why you want to use specifically a regexp?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mention in my comment, even if you get the  as string, you could create a in memory DOM element, and then access to the properties you need:

```
var text = '<meta charset="UTF-8" data-slide-length="5" data-prio="HIGH" data-freq="2">'

var temp = document.createElement("div");
temp.innerHTML = text;

alert(temp.firstChild.dataset.slideLength) // 5
```

After you collect all the info you need, you can set `temp` to `null`.

However, if for some reason you can't do so, the regexp you're looking for would be something similar to `/(\S+)="(.*?)"/g`, and then you need to iterate over the string:

var text = ''

```
var m, re = /(\S+)="(.*?)"/g;

while (m = re.exec(text)) {
  alert("key:" + m[1] + " value: " + m[2])  
}
```

From here you can create your object.

Comment: Sweet! This is the solution, with a small edit from me adding the `data-` to the regexp.
The hard part was apparently that I needed to loop the .exec() function. This is obviously written somewhere but I missed it.
Thank you soo much!

Answer (score 0):

A workaround can be use this text as XML and read data atributes with a parser if you know atribute names.

Comment: Don't really know how I would go about doing that. In my case I am reading five similar files and it's optional for them to have any extra `data-` attributes. Does this count as "knowing" the attributes?

Comment: What i comment is similar to @ZER0 first answer.