# How to get all data-* attribute names

Tags: jquery

I want to get array of all custom attribute name used in document/element
(e.g. data-abc, data-pqr)

Comment: some more info, please. What did you tried. How does your code look? What's the issue?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4190650/1823841

Answer (score 2):

Use `.data()` without passing any arguments.

```
$(element).data();

$( "body" ).data(); // { foo: 52, bar: { myType: "test", count: 40 }, baz: [ 1, 2, 3 ] }
```

The above gives all the `data-` attributes found in the tag as well as set by JavaScript.