# Tablesorter math widget use data-*

Tags: jquery, tablesorter

I am using Mottie's Tablesorter (https://github.com/Mottie/tablesorter) and i am trying to use the Math widget on cells that are formatted like this;

```
<td data-number="50">Fifty</td>
```

However i cant seem to find out how to pass `data-*` through to `arry` on the `math-complete` option;

```
  math_complete : function($cell, wo, result, value, arry) {
    var txt = '<span class="align-decimal">' +
      ( value === wo.math_none ? '' : '$ ' ) +
      result + '</span>';
    if ($cell.attr('data-math') === 'all-sum') {
      // when the "all-sum" is processed, add a count to the end
      return txt + ' (Sum of ' + arry.length + ' cells)';
    }
    return txt;
  }
```

Also, I am using v2.18.2.

[Documentation Link](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/example-widget-math.html)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4187032/get-list-of-data-attributes-using-javascript-jquery

Comment: I require that it is  integrated into TableSorter because I wish to use the `math_event` option. This solution is just a general jQuery solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The math widget is set up to get information from a data-attribute set by the [`textAttribute`](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/index.html#textattribute) option. So if you want to use `data-number`, set that attribute to `"data-number"` ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/abkNM/7203/)):

```
$(function () {
    $('table').tablesorter({
        theme: 'blue',
        textAttribute: 'data-number',
        widgets: ['zebra', 'math']
    });
});
```

Comment: What if you need to use `textAttribute` in some columns and the cell value in other columns?

Comment: The math widget only grabs data-attribute values if it exists, so if you want to use the cell value, don't add a `data-number` attribute. Or are you saying that non-math cells would get their sort messed up with this method?

Comment: I understand that, however, I have a case where I want to use the math widget on two different columns, `<td data-number="50">Fifty</td>` and `<td>20</td>` it seems to work correctly if i set textAttribute to `data-number`, where `data-number` isn't available it uses the default instead.