# Get all data attributes of an element and their value in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a element defined as follows:

```
<span class="road-btn js-road-btn" data-lat-s=' + row.LatL + ' data-lng-s=' + row.LongL + ' data-lat-e=' + row.LatD + ' data-lng-e=' + row.LongD +'> <i class="icon-pin"></i ></span >
```

I have performed a click event on this element as :

```
$('.js-road-btn').on('click', function () {
    var latS = $(this).attr('data-lat-s');
    var longS = $(this).attr('data-lng-s');
    var latE = $(this).attr('data-lat-e');
    var longE = $(this).attr('data-lng-e');
});
```

Instead of getting each attribute separately, I want to retrieve all the attributes values as a whole. Then I access the properties separaretly. How can I achieve this in jquery ?

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/data/.

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4187032/get-list-of-data-attributes-using-javascript-jquery

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get list of data-\* attributes using javascript / jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4187032/get-list-of-data-attributes-using-javascript-jquery)

Answer (score 4):

You could use the jQuery method **[`.data()`](https://api.jquery.com/data/)** like :

```
$(this).data(); //Will return the set of all the data-* attributes
```

```js
$('.js-road-btn').on('click', function() {
  var attributes = $(this).data();

  console.log(attributes);

  alert(attributes.lngE);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<span class="road-btn js-road-btn" data-lat-s='1' data-lng-s='2' data-lat-e='3' data-lng-e='4'> Click me </span >
```

Comment: I am getting `[object Object]`

Comment: Are you using `alert()` to output the result ?

Comment: `console.log`
Its ok.. I just had to append the properties with the data.

Comment: What I am doing is :

`var path = $(this).data();`

Then accessing the attribute like : path.data('lat-s')

Its throwing :
`path.data is not a function` 

Could you please help ?

Comment: You should get it like `path.latS` instead

Answer (score 2):

As the values are all stored in `data-*` attributes, you can use `data()` (with no arguments) to retrieve them all in a single object:

```js
$('.js-road-btn').on('click', function() {
  var data = $(this).data();
  console.log(data);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="road-btn js-road-btn" data-lat-s="lat-s" data-lng-s="lng-s" data-lat-e="lat-e" data-lng-e="lng-e"> 
  Click me
</span>
```

Comment: What I am doing is : `var path = $(this).data();` Then accessing the attribute like : `path.data('lat-s')` to log the value. Its throwing : `path.data` is not a function Could you please help ?

Comment: `path` is an object, so you just access its properties. It has no methods. `path.latS` should work for you

Comment: What if I want to specify the attribute name ?

Comment: Not sure what you mean

Comment: Like `'lat-s'`.

Comment: Ah, I see. That's not possible as the keys gets transcribed to remove `-` characters. For a better explanation of this [see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22753630/519413). If you did want that behaviour then you'd need to create the logic to scrape the attributes yourself.