# Jquery select multiple classes and extract data

Tags: jquery, html

I want to extract data from data- tags within multiple class elements. Is the each() function the best way to do this?

Jquery:

```
$('#copymodal').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {

            $(".copy19").each(function(){
                var a = data('total');
                alert(a);
            });
       })
```

HTML:

```
<a class='copy19' href='#'            
      data-statementid="14"
      data-total="98078"
      data-toggle="modal" 
      data-target="#editmodal">
      Edit
</a>

<a class='copy19' href='#'            
      data-statementid="16"
      data-total="78078"
      data-toggle="modal" 
      data-target="#editmodal">
      Edit
</a>
```

Comment: `$(this).data('total');`

Comment: It would be `$(this).data('total')`

Comment: Or `this.dataset.total`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get list of data-\* attributes using javascript / jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4187032/get-list-of-data-attributes-using-javascript-jquery)

Answer (score 1):

> extract data from data- tags within multiple class elements

Use `.map()` to get an array of values back: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.map/

```js
var totals = $(".copy19").map(function(i, e) {
    return $(e).data("total");
}).get();

console.log(totals)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class='copy19' href='#'            
      data-statementid="14"
      data-total="98078"
      data-toggle="modal" 
      data-target="#editmodal">
      Link
</a>

<a class='copy19' href='#'            
      data-statementid="16"
      data-total="78078"
      data-toggle="modal" 
      data-target="#editmodal">
      Link
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, each is one of the ways to do it as `$('.copy19')` returns a list of elements (basically an array).

Comment: For me itsn't :D the other answer shows the best way.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".copy19").each(function() {
    // Like this:
    var statementid = $(this).data('statementid');
    var total = $(this).data('total');
    var toggle = $(this).data('toggle');
    var target = $(this).data('target');

    // or like this..

    var allData = $(this)[0].dataset;
    /* value of allData is object with attributes:
    allData = {
        statementid: "14",
        total: "98078",
        toggle: "modal",
        target: "#editmodal"
    }
    */
});
```